# jQuery: if ID is equal to statement

Tags: jquery, html, attr, css-selectors

I'm working on a code that does a action if one of the LI's is selected.
So if one of the first LI's is 'current' I want to perform an action on it, the code:

```
<div id="types">
    <div id="division1">
        <ul id="selection1">
            <li id="current"><a href="#" name="1-1"></a> </li>
            <li><a href="#" name="1-2"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" name="1-3"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="division2">
        <ul id="selection2">
            <li><a href="#" name="2-1"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" name="2-2"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" name="2-3"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
if (jQuery("#types div ul:nth-child(1)").attr("ID") == "current") {
    *do this*
}
```

Anyone has any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I wouldn't change the IDs and use classes instead.

Comment: This is just not the only code, the other codes need the ID's for it to work out. This is just the idea.

Comment: Try to use `Class` instead of `ID` your trigger in current selected `anchor`.

Answer (score 4):

`ul` do not have id current but `li` does

try this -

```
if (jQuery("#types div ul:nth-child(1) li:first").attr("ID") == "current") {
    *do this*
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll throw my two cents in here

```
if($('#types div ul > li:first').is('#current')){
    *do this*
}
```

I threw out 1 pseudoselector, 1 extra function call and 1 comparison for the built in `is()` which I find to be a bit more readable.

And made a [Fiddle for demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LkK4r/)

## update

What you had faulty was that you had set `display:none` on the parent div `#Uitleg1, #Uitleg2` and when you tried to `.show()` on your child it inherited the `display:none`.

I updated the CSS with a new selector.

```
#Uitleg1, #Uitleg2 div {
    display: none;
}
```

and removed `display: none;` from the one above that. Your code now works as expected.

Made another [Fiddle for demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DtK39/31/)

Comment: Doesn't do the job. Maybe u can try? It's under: http://jsfiddle.net/disgeae/DtK39/29/ on "if ($("#CertificaatTypes div ul > li:first").is('#current')) {"

Comment: Well, the selector works indeed. If you place an alert() inside it alerts properly.

Comment: I have no idea how to refactor it.. :( I'm just a jQuery noobie. Any idea why the div isn't showing then.